# How does no nojsstats.appspot.com work?

Tags: web-services, google-analytics, noscript

I'm curious about: http://nojsstats.appspot.com

This service is meant for google-analytics users that want to track their pageviews and others things even if javascript is disabled.
I wonder how this service works and how it can determine the necessary data without javascript? I mean what is happening when I HTTP-GET to the site:

Example (HTML code):

`<img src="http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/mywebsite.com" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the link, you will see what it does.

The Example you gave is basically a short code for:

http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmn=93757836&utmsr=-&utmsc=-&utmul=-&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=-&utmhn=mywebsite.com&utmr=&utmp=&utmac=UA-123456........